# I can't seem to get with windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

This is my problem. I tried to install ubuntu on a pendrive. I mounted the ISO file onto the pendrive with yumi. I went booted ubuntu and when I go to the install were we can select the disk we want to install ubuntu on. My windows disk are shown up as /dev/mapper/ubuntu Vg-root. It seemed suspicious , so I came out of the installation and when I booted windows it is not booting up. Have I lost all my files and data pls help.

Comment: You might not have lost all data and files. Only the bootloader would need to be fixed. First to verify that your files are intact, go back to the installation USB. Choose **Try Ubuntu** instead on Install Ubuntu. This will lead you to a live system. You will find all your disk partitions(and files) in the **Files Application**. Check if they are intact. This might be a good time to back up them all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when i go into the "Files" i dont see any directories. there is only "Computer" with all the linux files. Have i just screwed my pc really bad?

Comment: Are you sure that your partitions are not showing up there? You might need to mount them by clicking on the partition, in order to browse the files inside them

Comment: If you are sure, you may want to start with recovery of data. See this answer https://askubuntu.com/q/286181. But better you should look around more and be sure that your partitions have been really deleted or not. But do not write any data into the hard disk because it will decrease the chances of successful data recovery

Comment: Try to look into the status of your disk, the partitions currently on it with the help of Gparted(available in Try Ubuntu, search in dash)